# Routing "static network ip" through VPN? (Windows)

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, routing

I´d like to route different static network IPs through different VPNs on a windows server/pc.
Here an example:

192.168.179.100 -> route through VPN 1

192.168.179.101 -> route through VPN 2

etc

I don´t want to use VPN routers because I have like 200 different network clients and each of them needs its own VPN. The clients are machines and no PCs. So I can´t run a VPN on themself.

I hope someone can help me here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the `route` command to insert static host routes on the server:

```
route ADD 192.168.179.100 MASK 255.255.255.255  157.55.80.1 METRIC 3 IF 2
    target^               ^Mask                 ^gateway    metric^
                                                            interface^
```

The speciality here is the host route, denoted by the '255.255.255.255' netmask. The route will then only be followed for this exact one IP address.